# Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Фасуется строго по одному экземпляру в предварительно украшенную деревянную упаковку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые отсутствуют.

**Фасуется (как?) строго по одному экземпляру // (куда?) в предварительно украшенную деревянную упаковку.**

Запятые обычно хочется поставить на месте пауз, но их постановка должна объясняться **грамматически**. А для этого надо понимать структуру предложения.

Здесь мы имеем два обстоятельства (как? и куда?), **но они не являются однородными**. Также нет оснований для сближения значений, чтобы считать их однородными.

А небольшая **пауза** между ними, обозначающая перелом интонации, всё-таки делается.

Answer (score 1):

Запятые здесь не нужны. Где вам хочется ее поставить?

Comment: думала нужно как-то выделить "предварительно украшенную"

Comment: Но это распространенное определение стоит ПЕРЕД определяемым словом, а не после. А потом – чувствуете, что вам тогда пришлось бы ставить запятую после предлога? Как бы это выглядело?

Answer (score 1):

Контекста нет, но я вижу ***теоретическую*** возможность постановки в предложении запятой, и даже тире.
Представим себе инструктаж мастера в упаковочном отделе.

1. — Фасуется строго по одному экземпляру в предварительно украшенную, деревянную упаковку. Повторяю для всех ещё раз: деревянную упаковку!

Ситуация такая: вчера фасовка производилась, например, в картонную или пластиковую тару (упор делается ее на фактуре).

2. — Фасуется строго по одному экземпляру — в предварительно украшенную деревянную упаковку. По одному — в дерево.

Ситуация такая: по одному (именно одному) экземпляру чего-то упаковывается в деревянную (именно в деревянную) тару — можно поставить интонационное тире.
Вполне возможно, что два или три экземпляра продукции помещаются в другую упаковку (в бархат или в кожу — как дорогой шотландский виски).

Comment: А я вижу и практическую возможность. _- А какие меры в транспортном цехе принимаются при фасовке для сохранности этого ценного продукта? - Их две. Фасуется строго по одному экземпляру(, /и) в предварительно украшенную деревянную упаковку._

Answer (score 0):

"Предварительно украшенную деревянную упаковку" действительно никак не нужно разграничивать запятыми. Однако выделение "предварительно окрашенной" необходимо на основании того, что это [обстоятельство,](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_177) выраженное - внезапно! - [причастным оборотом](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-148.htm), при этом возможно наличие запятой внутри самого оборота и предложение получает такой вид:

...по одному экземпляру(,) в предварительно украшенную(,) деревянную упаковку.

Возможность постановки запятой между словами "украшенную" и "деревянную" зависит от намерения автора и возможна по следующим основаниям:

1. Если определение "деревянная" [уточняет](https://www.portal-slovo.ru/philology/37406.php) свойства упаковки (уточняющее определение).
2. Если определение "деревянная" [поясняет](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html) свойства упаковки.